# Is there a premium version of Google translate that is available for purchase to integrate into business applications?

Tags: google-apps

It looks like there may have been at one time a version of Google translate called "Business" that did not employ the free API used by the version that comes up in my browser. If there is, how can I get more information about it (I've already googled it and cannot find anything)? If not, is there some kind of replacement that can be used in its stead?

Comment: Are you after https://cloud.google.com/translate/ ?

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, that was correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Tensibai Could you post this comment as an answer so that this answer will be removed from the unanswered tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes !

There's an API available on Google Cloud & you can find more details about it on https://cloud.google.com/translate/